# JQuery Menu Icon RTL

Tags: jquery, right-to-left

I am trying to use jQuery menu in an Arabic RTL page. I am able to make it RTL but the icon should be `ui-icon-carat-1-w` not `ui-icon-carat-1-e`. I created [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/daliaessam/b39ngu8g/). How do I change the direction of the arrows in sub menus, so they show the `carat-1-w` instead of `the carat-1-e`?

Also, is there any CSS reset for RTL support for jQuery to make jQuery RTL and Arabic enabled.

```css
body {
    text-align: right;
}

*{
    direction: rtl
}

a, a:link, a:visited{
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Arial,Verdana,Tahoma,Times,Sans-Serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.ui-menu {
    float: right;
}

.ui-menu .ui-menu-icon {
    right: auto;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu" style="width: 200px;">
    <li><a href="#">العربية</a>
        <ul id="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">حسابات</a></li>
            <li>ادارة</li>    
            <li>رصيد</li>
        </ul> 
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">تسجيل</a></li>    
<li><a href="#">اتصال</a></li>
</ul>    


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menu').menu();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/b39ngu8g/6/)***

```
$('#menu').menu({
    icons: { submenu: "ui-icon-carat-1-w" },
    position: { my: "right top", at: "left-5 top-2"}
});
```

CSS:

```
.ui-menu .ui-menu-icon {
  float:left;
}
```

see also: http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/#option-icons and http://api.jqueryui.com/position/

Comment: Perfect!. Can this be done only by CSS without JS?. This may be another question if you want, I created a new fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/daliaessam/p3Lsk2cm/1/ the sub sub menus floats to left, any fix?

Comment: @daliaessam sure you can, you can set the icon background position to match the one of "w"(west), but ragarding position you need to do it using the UI: http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/p3Lsk2cm/4/. Actually I'd do it all in the method object, without messing with CSS too much. That's why it's a plugin right?

Comment: Good, I will go with the jquery solution as you suggested over the css. I have a new issue on this subject and created a new question for it anyway here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27359663/jquery-menu-plugin-extend-for-rtl-auto-support-with-default-options