# JQuery menu plugin extend for RTL auto support with default options

Tags: jquery

This is a follow up on my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27349023/jquery-menu-icon-rtl). I have created almost a plugin to automatically detect the page direction and set default options to force the menu plugin to work RTL and change the sub menus icon to work also RTL. I created this [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/daliaessam/8pw9mpv0/).

My question the code I used to detect will be executed on every menu call as I have on some pages about 20 menus, will this consume a lot of time, can this be done/checked once on page load. Can this code in general be optimized as a plugin.

```
body {
    text-align: right;
}

*{
    direction: rtl
}

a, a:link, a:visited{
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Arial,Verdana,Tahoma,Times,Sans-Serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.ui-menu {
    float: right;
}
.ui-menu .ui-menu-icon {
  float:left;  
}
<ul id="menu" style="width: 200px;">
    <li><a href="#">العربية</a>
        <ul id="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">حسابات</a>
                <ul id="subsubmenu">
                    <li><a href="#">حسابات</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ادارة</a></li>    
                    <li><a href="#">رصيد</a></li>
                </ul> 

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">ادارة</a></li>    
                <li><a href="#">رصيد</a></li>
        </ul> 
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">تسجيل</a></li>    
<li><a href="#">اتصال</a></li>
</ul>    

(function($){
    var menu_orig = $.fn.menu;
    // ...before overwriting the jQuery extension point
    $.fn.menu = function(options) { 
        var isRTL = isRTL || (($("body").css("direction").toLowerCase() == "rtl")? 1 : 0);
        if (isRTL) {
            if (typeof options === "object") {
                options = $.extend(true, options, {
                    icons: {submenu: "ui-icon-circle-triangle-w"},
                    position: {my: "right top", at: "left top"}
                });
            }
        }

        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
        var ret = menu_orig.apply(this, args);
        return ret;
    };
    //----------------------------------------
})(jQuery);

$('#menu').menu({
});
```

Comment: `"can this be done/checked"` ? what exactly? `"on every menu call"` ? what call? you've extended the original plugin. What's wrong with the code above?

Comment: I have a little bit experience with jquery and JS in general, the code `var isRTL = isRTL || (($("body").css("direction").toLowerCase() == "rtl")? 1 : 0);` is used to check the RTL/direction, will this slow the page and I am asking also experts to rewrite/format the code as a professional code because I only tweaked another code without experience.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with some code for jquery menus and menubar better if some one make it official plugin.

```
function supportRTL() {
    //----------------------------------------
    // menu plugin to auto detect RTL and set menus for RTL
    // http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Context.2C_Call_and_Apply
    //----------------------------------------
    var menu_orig = $.fn.menu;
    $.fn.menu = function(options) { 
        if (typeof options === "object") {
            options = $.extend(true, {
                icons: {submenu: "ui-icon-carat-1-w"},
                position: {my: "right top", at: "left top"}
            }, options);
        }
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
        var ret = menu_orig.apply(this, args);
        return ret;
    };
    //----------------------------------------
    // menubar plugin to auto detect RTL and set menus for RTL
    var menubar_orig = $.fn.menubar;
    $.fn.menubar = function(options) {  
        if (typeof options === "object") {
            options = $.extend(true, {
                position: {my: "right top", at: "right bottom"} // RTL support
            }, options);
        }
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
        var ret = menubar_orig.apply(this, args);
        return ret;
    };
}


$(document).ready(function () {
    var is_rtl = ($("body").css("direction").toLowerCase() == "rtl")? 1 : 0;
    $.fn.isRTL = function() {return is_rtl;}
    if ($.fn.isRTL()){
        supportRTL();
    }
});
```